# What is an Amperian man?

Tags: electromagnetism, reference-frames, terminology, coordinate-systems

In Cagniard(1953), Basic theory of the magneto-telluric method of geophysical prospecting he writes,

[image]

> "If a current circulates in the ground along OX, OY is at the left of the Amperian man looking up at the sky."

What is an Amperian man?

Comment: Please include the context in your quotation. This is probably explained in the book.

Comment: My wild guess would be some antique form of a right-hand rule.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this concerns a concept in geophysics and seems a better fit to Earth Sciences SE.